# Restart PHP-FPM Gateway via a PHP Script in Linux Server

Tags: php, linux, nginx, sudo

I am running a LEMP stack and wish to write a simple control panel for it.

So, I want to be able to restart `php-fpm` from a php script. To achieve this, this is what I did.

Created a binary wrapper in `c` like this **php-shell.c**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_CMN_LEN 100

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char cmd[MAX_CMN_LEN] = "", **p;

    if (argc < 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: ./php_shell terminal_command ...");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else
    {
        strcat(cmd, argv[1]);
        for (p = &argv[2]; *p; p++)
        {
            strcat(cmd, " ");
            strcat(cmd, *p);
        }
        system(cmd);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This program was compiled like this:

```
gcc php_shell.c -o php_shell
```

I have then added nginx user to `sudo visudo` like this:

```
Defaults:nginx        !requiretty
nginx    ALL=(ALL)    NOPASSWD:/path/to/php_shell
```

Then I executed the command in a php script like this:

```
var_dump(shell_exec('sudo /path/to/php_shell "service nginx restart" 2>&1'));
```

As soon as I run this script php script, I get `502 Gateway Error` and it appears all `php-fpm` processes has been killed off and it does not start back up.

Any ideas? Am I doing this wrong? I want to achieve the same for nginx (i.e. be able to restart nginx server from php script by executing `service nginx restart`). How can I achieve this?

Comment: The php-fpm is to be shutdown when `restart`. So it is aborted to execute the `shell_exec`method , and get `502 Bad Gateway`. I recommend you can use the `Nginx + Lua` to execute the script to restart `php-fpm`. [OpenResyt](http://openresty.org) is easy to use.

Comment: Instead of creating your own wrapper, you may want to look at monitoring / restart tools such as Monit (https://mmonit.com/monit/) ?